# Python to Open .npy File

Tags: python, numpy

Nowadays i study machine learning using Python and Numpy.

After installing Keras, i started to see this thing.

then i found mnist.npz file. 
(mnist.npz is basic handwriting example for study machine learning)

I was curious about mnist.npz. so i try to open it.

i have coded this

---

```
import numpy as np

x = np.load("C:/mnist.npz")
print (x)
```

---

(the npz file is in drive C)

then computer show this

---

```
<numpy.lib.npyio.NpzFile object at 0x000001F1BE7E6A58>
```

---

??????????????what?????????

What does computer mean by this?

so i tried the other way. i have coded this

---

```
import numpy as np

x = np.load("C:/mnist.npz")
print(x['y_test'])
```

---

so computer show this.

---

```
[7 2 1 ... 4 5 6]
```

---

why show [...]?!?!?!?!?!?!?
Why do not computer show me all array? Show me all!

example... computer can show me `[7 2 1 1 2 3 4 4 5 6]`!!

But the computer does not. computer does not show it all.

I want to see all elements of an array.

how to see all elements in `.npz` and `.npy` files???????

Google has no answer.

Answer (score 1):

Set the printing options for numpy

```
np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.inf)
```

Comment: ㄴThis is what I wanted to know. thanks you! thanks you!